# One extra radio button is getting printed in div in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to copy one row of a table and append a radio button to it. There are 3 rows that i declared in the html and an add button in jquery which can add names to the table. All of these rows are appended with a delete button. when I click the start button I want the names to go to the next div without the delete button and append a radio button to it. and the user should be able to vote the names.when i add names, an extra radio button without name value is passed to the div. I can't figure out why. I'm trying to make a voting system using jquery without using any databases(temporary). Please help. I can't figure out why the extra radio button is getting passed. It's only passed when i add candidate using the add button.

here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#start').click(function()
    { 
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#buttonset1").hide();
        $("#div2").show();
        $("#voterName").val("")
        if( $('#candidateTable thead tr').children().length = 1)
        {
            if( $('#newTable thead').children().length == 0 )
            {
                $('#newTable thead').append('<tr></tr>');
            }
            $('#newTable thead tr').append('<th>' + $($('#candidateTable thead tr').children()).text() + '</th>');
            $('#candidateTable tbody tr').each(function(i)
            {
                if( $('#newTable tbody').children().length != $('#candidateTable tbody').children().length)
                {
                    $('#newTable tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
                }
                $('#newTable tbody tr:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').append('<td>' + $($(this).children()[0]).text()+'</td>'+'<td><input type="radio" class="radiobutton"></td>');
            });
        }

    });

    //delete candiates

    $("#candidateTable").on('click', '.del', function()
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    //add candidate

    $("#add").click(function()
    {
    //adding candidates
    
        var candidatename = $("#candidatename").val();
        if(candidatename.length!=0)
        {
            $("#candidateTable tbody").append('<tr><td>'+ candidatename +'</td>'+'<td>'+'<button class="del" id="Delete">Delete</button>'+'</td><tr>');
            $("#candidatename").val('');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#final").click(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div4").show();
    });
});
```

```css
table, tr, th, td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Voting System </h1>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <table id="candidateTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th id="candidatelist">Candidate Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>XXXX</td>
                    <td><button class="del" id="Delete">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>YYYY</td>
                    <td><button class="del" id="Delete">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ZZZZ</td>
                    <td><button class="del" id="Delete">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonset1">
        <br>
        <br>
            <input type="text" id="candidatename"> 
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        <br>
        <br>
            <button id="start">Start</button>
        <br>
        <br>        
    </div>
    <br>
    <form action="javascript:void(0)">
    <div id="div2" style="display: none;">
        <div id="buttonset2">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="votername">
        <button id="vote">Vote</button>
        <br>
        <br>

        <table id="newTable">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="final">Submit Votes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="div4" style="display:none;">
        <h2>
            Result
        </h2>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add jQuery to your snippet so it could be executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of code:

```
$("#candidateTable tbody").append('<tr><td>'+ candidatename +'</td>'+'<td>'+'<button class="del" id="Delete">Delete</button>'+'</td><tr>');
```

with this:

```
$("#candidateTable tbody").append('<tr><td>'+ candidatename +'</td><td><button class="del" id="Delete">Delete</button></td></tr>');
```

in your add function. Now it will not add one extra row.

Full working example link is below

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/fkeler/pen/xxXWxbE?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=gHjNN7PENtO2Xsh2Ic9_ak5t.J44WoXywT5yIp45ifA-1640936402-0-gaNycGzNCb0)

Comment: If you mark my answer as the accepted one, it may help others. Thanks.